# Issue: Argument #1 ($user) must be of type Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null given, called in

Tags: php, laravel

I'm beginner in Laravel. I'm using jetstream for auth. When I trying register to database, it saves to database but gives this error. So how can I fix this problem

**My HomeController is:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    protected $user;


    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            $this->user= Auth::user();

            return $next($request);
        });
    }

    public function main(){
        return view('welcome');
    }

    public function home(){
        return view('design2.index');
    }

    public function logout(Request $request) {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/');
      }

    public function register(){
        return view('design2.registerpage');
    }

    public function login_page(){
        return view('design2.loginpage');
    }

    public function profile(){
        return view('profile');
    }

}
```

My user model is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Fortify\TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
use Laravel\Jetstream\HasProfilePhoto;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
    use HasProfilePhoto;
    use Notifiable;
    use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'two_factor_recovery_codes',
        'two_factor_secret',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'profile_photo_url',
    ];
}
```

My CreateNewUser is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Actions\Fortify;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\CreatesNewUsers;
use Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream;

class CreateNewUser implements CreatesNewUsers
{
    use PasswordValidationRules;

    /**
     * Validate and create a newly registered user.
     *
     * @param  array  $input
     * @return \App\Models\User
     */
    public function create(array $input)
    {
        Validator::make($input, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => $this->passwordRules(),
            
            
        ])->validate();

        $save = User::create([
            'name' => $input['name'],
            'email' => $input['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
        ]);
 

    }
}
```

Error is:

**Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login(): Argument #1 ($user) must be of type Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null given, called in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/muzik/vendor/laravel/fortify/src/Http/Controllers/RegisteredUserController.php on line 56**

Comment: Error is in `RegisteredUserController.php`, so add that file too.

Comment: @MartinOsusky is this?

Comment: My mistake, I didn't realize that this file is 'vendor'. But what you've added is also useful.

Comment: Try to return created user. `return User::create([ ... ]);` instead of just save in variable `$save`

Answer (score 0):

Try to return created user instead of just save it in variable `$save`.

```php
    public function create(array $input)
    {
        Validator::make($input, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => $this->passwordRules(),                     
        ])->validate();

        return User::create([
            'name' => $input['name'],
            'email' => $input['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: not getting any error but I can't register to database now

Comment: What does it mean "I can't register to database NOW"? What else did it do before you added returning of created user?

Comment: bro, my code can register to database but it was getting that error. when I try run with your code, not getting any error but I can't register to database. simple. why are u screaming? I'm beginner I don't know what is the problem

Comment: I will try to ask otherwise, so "register in the database" means create a user record in the database? And before you added the return of the created user it worked and when you return this created user, won't it create it in the database? If an error occurs in the log, add it here please.